# laravel 8 - crop image and upload

Tags: php, html, ajax, laravel

I'm using Laravel 8 and I'm beginner. I want to crop image and upload but when I select image, the name of the image appears on the screen but when I crop and submit I can't see the name of the image(I don't know maybe not uploading). How can I upload the image? Or How can I fix it? I'm using 'ijaboCropTool' by the way.

**My controller is:**

```
public function contentPost(request $request){

        $request->validate([
            
            'title' => ['string', 'max:128'],
            'short_content' => ['string', 'max:256'],
            'content' => ['string'],
            'first_photo' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,svg|max:2048',
            
            
        ]);


        $dest = 'images/test_post/';
        $file = $request->file('first_photo');
        $new_image_name = 'UIMG'.date('YmdHis').uniqid().'.jpg';

        $move = $file->move(public_path($dest),$new_image_name);

        if(!$move){
            return response()->json(['status'=>0,'msg'=>'falseee']);
        }else{
            return response()->json(['status'=>1,'msg'=>'trueee','name'=>$new_image_name]);
        }
        

    
        $title = $request->title;
        $short = $request->short_content;
        $content = $request->content;



        $save = Post::create([
            'title' => $title,
            'short_content' => $short,
            'content' => Purifier::clean($content),
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'first_photo' => $filename,

            
        ]);

     

        if($save){
            return back()->with('success','successs');
        }else{
            return back()->with('error','errorr');
        }


    }
```

My blade.php is:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{route('contentPost')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload_image_form" >

                @csrf

                <div class="form-group p-3">
                  <label for="">Change picture</label>
                  <input type="file" name="first_photo" id="first_photo">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <input class="form-control" maxlength="128" name='title'  required="" autofocus="">
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-lg-12">
                      <textarea class="form-control" maxlength="256"  rows="2" name="short_content"></textarea>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-lg-12">
                      <!-- <textarea class="form-control" rows="16" name="content" ></textarea> -->
                      <input id="content" type="hidden" name="content">
                      <trix-editor  input="content"></trix-editor>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input type="submit" class="site-btn" value="save">
                    <span></span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
```

**My ajax is:**

```
$('#first_photo').ijaboCropTool({
        processUrl: '{{route("contentPost")}}',
        allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'jpeg','png'],
        withCSRF:['_token','{{ csrf_token() }}'],
        setRatio:1,
        onSuccess:function(message, element, status){
          alert(message);
          },
        onError:function(message, element, status){
          alert(message);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in your controller.
If I'm not wrong, you're not saving your cropped image.

This is my controller. Notice that I'm first selecting the user to update the picture on database and then I save the image.

```
function crop(Request $request){

        $user = User::where('id', auth()->user()->id)
            ->first();
            
        $path = '/storage/user/picture';
        $picture = $request->file('picture');
        $new_image_name = 'UIMG'.date('Ymd').uniqid().'.jpg';
        $upload = $picture->move(public_path($path), $new_image_name);
        if($upload){
            $user->update(['picture' => $new_image_name]);
            return response()->json(['status'=>1, 'msg'=>'Message for success', 'name'=>$new_image_name]);
        }else{
              return response()->json(['status'=>0, 'msg'=>'Message for error']);
        }
      }
```